# DJI Zenmuse Z3 Pinout

Tags: pinout

Can anyone explain this pinout diagram? I only know that D+/- AMBA & DM are USB D+/- and H&L are for the CAN bus. What are do the blue and red contacts mean?[image]

Comment: Most likely just supply and ground
Blue being ground, V+ being red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stolen from http://cosmostreamer.com/wired/howtomake, I would say it is safe to assume that it is indeed power+ and power-. The images are not directly from the zenmuse but from the Inspire adapter, which I think is perfectly compatible with the zenmuse 3 as taken from the site

> Flying with the Zenmuse Z3 is as simple as attaching it to the DJI Inspire 1

[image]